# Practical way to parse a float with newlib without locale support

Tags: c, locale, nios, atof, newlib

I'm experimenting with NIOS II soft core, trying to minimize the footprint of my embedded app. One of the biggest gains I get comes from using the small C library ([p 206](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/nios2/n2sw_nii5v2gen2.pdf)):

> The full newlib library functionality is often unnecessary for embedded systems, and undesirably large for systems needing a minimal RAM footprint. Altera provides a reduced-functionality reduced-size "Small C" version of 
>   newlib  which allows smaller RAM footprints to be achieved.

One of the features stripped down from small C library is the locale support. However, when I try to use `atof()`, the linking fails because it calls `localeconv()` which is not there. For example, building the following sample

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) { return atof("0"); }
```

results in "/path/to/[strtod.c:341](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/strtod.c): undefined reference to `_localeconv_r`" error. It's really a shame since the only thing `atof()` needs is the `decimal_point` definition.

What options do I have if I need to parse floats, besides including a modified copy of `strtod.c` in my software? Using regular C library (instead of the small one) increases my code footprint by 35kB which is a big deal for embedded SW.

Comment: Can you code your own `localeconv/_localeconv_r()` and link?  Or at least try that to verify this is the only remaining hurdle?

Comment: Often, just whispering 'floating point support' causes a build fail on memory space:(   Can you not get rid of all floats?

Comment: I hope that `atol()` instead of `atof()` in your example is just a typo?

Comment: try `-libintl` on linking.  Probably you have it separate.

Comment: @MartinJames What I do is a kind of framework, and in most use cases the floating point support is indeed not required. I want to have it if possible, but of course not at a price of 35kB for every user.